# How do i move one activity to another in Recycler View?

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Well , i'm having a trouble (i use kotlin) i need to pass from [Menu_cliente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxElw.jpg) to [create_clients_upd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ooagy.jpg) whit the information from the row i click , i want to move from a layout to another by clicking in the recyclerView (item 'vector' only  illustrative), and when clicking it was supost to present the data in the correct field to be able to change the information (update).

it was working in another way (whit a dialogbox ) but i need to improve to this way , and be able to update and delete from the create_clients_upd..

**update 2**

[the update made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtu8F.png)

**Update Object code**

```
@Parcelize class clientes (
var codigo_cliente: Int = 0,
var nome_cliente: String? = "",
var morada_cliente: String? = "",
var localidade_cliente: String? = "",
var postal_cliente: String? = "",
var contribuinte_cliente: String? = "",
var telefone_cliente: String? = "",
var pais_cliente: String? = ""): Parcelable


2020-03-06 16:39:42.342 10121-10121/com.example.jetpackteste E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.jetpackteste, PID: 10121
kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: not implemented
    at com.example.jetpackteste.Dados.IS4.onUpgrade(IS4.kt:53)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:417)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:341)
    at com.example.jetpackteste.Dados.IS4.getClient(IS4.kt:62)
    at com.example.jetpackteste.Menu_Clientes.verClientes(Menu_Clientes.kt:84)
    at com.example.jetpackteste.Menu_Clientes.onCreate(Menu_Clientes.kt:75)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

**Adapter**

```
class clientesAdapter(mCtx: Context, val clientes: ArrayList<clientes>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<clientesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    val mCtx = mCtx

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val IDcliente_view = itemView.IDcliente_view
        val Name_view = itemView.Name_view
        //val delete_button = itemView.delete_button
        val info_view = itemView.info_view
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): clientesAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.menu_client_app, p0, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    // cria linhas consoante a criação dos dados
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return clientes.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: clientesAdapter.ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        val client: clientes = clientes[p1]
        p0.IDcliente_view.text = client.codigo_cliente.toString()
        p0.Name_view.text = client.nome_cliente
    }
}
```

**RecyclerView**

```
    private fun  verClientes(){
        val clienteslista = IS4.getClient(this)
        val adapter = clientesAdapter(this,clienteslista)
        val rv : RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv)
        rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL,false) as RecyclerView.LayoutManager
        rv.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        verClientes()
        super.onResume()
    }
```

**Data Base**

```
fun update_cliente(id: String, codigo_cliente: Int, nome_cliente: String, morada_cliente: String, localidade_cliente: String, postal_cliente: String, contribuinte_cliente: String, telefone_cliente: String, pais_cliente: String) : Boolean {
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    val contentValues = ContentValues()
    var result = false
    contentValues.put(DB_Cliente_Codigo,codigo_cliente)
    contentValues.put(DB_Cliente_Nome,nome_cliente)
    contentValues.put(DB_Cliente_Morada,morada_cliente)
    contentValues.put(DB_Cliente_Localidade,localidade_cliente)
    contentValues.put(DB_Cliente_Postal,postal_cliente)
    contentValues.put(DB_Cliente_Contribuinte,contribuinte_cliente)
    contentValues.put(DB_Cliente_Telefone,telefone_cliente)
    contentValues.put(DB_Cliente_Pais,pais_cliente)

    try {
        db.update(CLIENTES_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "$DB_Cliente_Codigo = ?", arrayOf(id))
        result = true
    } catch (e : Exception){
        Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "Erro ao atualizar")
        result = false

    }
    return result
}
```

**create_clients_upd edittext var**

IDinput_upd

Nomeinput_upd

Moradainput_upd

Localidadeinput_upd

cod1_upd

Contribuinteinput_upd

Telefoneinput_upd

Zonainput_upd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first modify adapter with following:

```
class clientesAdapter(mCtx: Context, val clientes: ArrayList<clientes>, val onItemClick: (clientes) -> Unit) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<clientesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    val mCtx = mCtx

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): clientesAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.menu_client_app, p0, false)
        return ViewHolder(v, onItemClick)
    }

    // cria linhas consoante a criação dos dados
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return clientes.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: clientesAdapter.ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        val client: clientes = clientes[p1]
        p0.IDcliente_view.text = client.codigo_cliente.toString()
        p0.Name_view.text = client.nome_cliente
        p0.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            p0.onItemClick(client)
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View, val onItemClick: (clientes) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val IDcliente_view = itemView.IDcliente_view
        val Name_view = itemView.Name_view
        //val delete_button = itemView.delete_button
        val info_view = itemView.info_view
    }
}
```

I added Unit parameter to adapters and viewholders constructors. Unit works like interface listener in Java.

then modify method where you assign adapter to recyclerview:

```
   private fun  verClientes(){
        val clienteslista = getClient(this)
        val adapter = clientesAdapter(this, clienteslista) { cliente ->
            val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("cliente_key", cliente)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        val rv : RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv)
        rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL,false) as RecyclerView.LayoutManager
        rv.adapter = adapter
    }
```

modify your `cliente` object:

```
@Parcelize
class clientes(...your params...): Parcelable
```

if you will not be able to import `@Parcelize` add this to your build.gradle.
https://android.jlelse.eu/yet-another-awesome-kotlin-feature-parcelize-5439718ba220

you will get passed `cliente` object in DetailActivity's getIntent() method which you will use to show your datas:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val cliente = intent.extras?.getParcelable<cliente>("cliente_key")
}
```

use `cliente` model to fill input boxes

Comment: it worked to open the clicklistener, but , it doesn't show the data in the editext.. he should be whit that code?

Comment: is your `clientes` object in java or kotlin?

Comment: kotlin, is everything in kotlin... , i inserted ur code , worked perfectly , i tried insert the data in the field but i didn't sucess , i'm bad whit sql :/

Comment: I updated my answer. can you try again with latest codes

Comment: i updated my question , when u mean object u mean the model right? if is that i think i did correctly but he sends a error message , can u verify if is that u mean? pls

Comment: yes, i mean model. can you send error you're getting?

Comment: forgot i corrrected the error , but the info still dont show into the inputboxes , he should show the info like the second image when we click in any item :/

Comment: you will get passed cliente object in DetailActivity's getIntent() method. i've added to the end of my answer.

Comment: what means client key? and the val clientes is not in use like it shows in the update 2 (updated the question) , sorry to be so newbie!!

Comment: try to uninstall app from phone. it looks like the error you get from db when you change model

Comment: can we talk in the chat? pls

Comment: sure. vizier.freelance@gmail.com

Comment: i have no reputation enought  to create

Comment: me neither. mail me

Answer (score 0):

I am not used to kotlin but you can convert the following code from kotlin to java.

You can create an interface in RecyclerView Adapter class something like this

```
public interface onItemClick{
 void onClick(View v,ModelClass modelclass);
}
```

In class ViewHolder, add click listener to the vector image like

```
imageView.setOnClickLister(v->onItemClick.onClick(v, listItems.get(getAdapterPosition())))
```

The Constructor of clientesAdapter should have onItemClick as a parameter.

Now in your MainActivity

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearManager(this));
recyclerView.setAdapter(arrayList,new OnItemClick){
 @Override
        public void onClick(View view, ReflectionsMainItems reflectionsMainItems) {
            if (view.getID==R.id.imageView) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                SecondActivity.class).putExtras("ID",id));
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean convert?

Comment: imageView.setOnClickLister(v->onItemClick.onClick(v, listItems.get(getAdapterPosition()))) , and he shouldnt use the vector to switch layouts , but all the box :)
-- he doesnt convert to kotlin